# Pass URL from data- on href to another href in modal window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, custom-data-attribute

I am trying to pass a URL which I have as a value of data-url on an anchor tag to another anchor tag with the role of button. It loads in a modal window after the anchor on the page is clicked.  I think the issue is that the modal is loading as a result of the click event; however when I look in the console the URL is present.  When I click on the button in the modal or look at the href in the DOM, it is empty.  What is missing from my code?

```
<a href="javascript:void(0); data-sbUrl="http://linktopass.com">click</a>

$('.order-item-tracking').on('click', function(e) {
var sbTargetUrl = $(this).attr("data-sbUrl");
$('.modalBtn').attr('href', sbTargetUrl);
});
```

Comment: use prop() instead of attr()

Comment: Can you share your exact HTML?

Comment: You can use $(this).data('sbUrl');